# Bizarre solutions of a first order PDE

Tags: differential-equations

```
DSolve[{x y D[u[x,y],x]+(x-y)y D[u[x,y],y]+x==u[x,y],u[x,0]==x},u,{x,y}]
```

returns unevaluated. Removing the initial condition:

```
sol = DSolve[x y D[u[x, y], x] + (x - y) y D[u[x, y], y] + x == u[x, y], u, {x, y}]
```

gives something complicated; then

```
Simplify[u[x, 0] /. sol, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
```

returns

```
{\[Piecewise]   Indeterminate   x==0
-((x (-\[Infinity] Hypergeometric2F1[1,1+1/x,2+1/x,-\[Infinity]]
    + (1 + x) Hypergeometric2F1[1,1/x,1+1/x,-\[Infinity]]))/(1+x))  x>0
x + \[Infinity] C[1][-(x^2/2)]  True
}
```

which, if I understand it correctly, means that the solution is undefined at `y=0` for real `x`.

I found several terms in the power series expansion "by hand", it goes like

```
x + xy/(1-x) + (xy)^2/((1-x)^2(1-2x)) + 2(2 - 3x)(xy)^3/((1-x)^3(1-2x)^2(1-3x))
+ 2(17 - 92x + 159x^2 - 90x^3)(xy)^4/((1-x)^4(1-2x)^3(1-3x)^2(1-4x))
+ 8(62 - 788x + 4048x^2 - 10783x^3 + 15759x^4 - 12042x^5 + 3780x^6)(xy)^5
   /((1-x)^5(1-2x)^4(1-3x)^3(1-4x)^2(1-5x))
```

so that at least in the formal sense the solution seems to exist.

Can I somehow extract an explicit solution from all this?

Comment: I would say not the solutions are bizarre but the PDE. The [characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) of this equation can be plotted with `StreamPlot[{x*y,(x-y)*y},{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},FrameLabel->{"x","y"}]`. Some never come close to $y=0$. Where does this equation come from and why are you interested in it?

Comment: @user293787 Very interesting observation! The equation is satisfied by the generating function for a recurrence from [a recent mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/427376/41291)

Comment: @user293787 and, on closer inspection, there is actually a discontinuity along `y=0`:  oppositely directed streamlines clash there.

Answer (score 5):

Not every PDE has an analytic solution. But you can always try a numerical solution:

```
reg = Disk[{0, 0}, 1];
0 reg = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]
sol = u /. 
  NDSolve[{x y D[u[x, y], x] + (x - y) y D[u[x, y], y] + x == u[x, y],
      u[x, 0] == x}, u, {x, y} \[Element] reg][[1]]
Plot3D[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Your boundary condition isn't actually a boundary condition - it's merely a necessary condition.  Consider the simpler case of xu'[x]==u[x].  u[0]==0 is necessary, but tells you nothing.
2. As you noticed from the comments, the Streamplot shows singular behavior for y=0, and to a lesser extent, x=0 and x=y as well.
3. Hypergeometric is literally a series expansion.  Mathematica uses it when normal analytic methods fail.
4. Looking at your series expansion, I'm assuming you expanded it in powers of y.  Well, your 5th term has a pole at x=1/5, and a 5th order pole at x=1.  If I had to guess, you're faced with a sequence of poles that approach x=0.  Maybe those terms will converge for sufficiently large x, but I doubt they're useful for real x between (0,1).  It's also another hint that y=0 is highly singular.
5. I used the substitution v=u-x.  This results in `xy(dv/dx+1)+(x-y)y(dv/dy)=v`.  If it weren't for that pesky +1 term, this would be linear.  Since you're interested in y=0, we can estimate local behavior in some epsilon ball of (0,0) by dumping that +1.  Looking at that solution, it's clear that y=0 is highly singular.

Overall, the PDE itself is naughty, and mathematica can't fix that.  Given the comments, you can give streamplot3d a try (doesn't work on wolfram alpha :()

Comment: Thank you, this is most informative! The question though is mostly about how to understand the output of Mathematica in this case. Because it seems to produce *some* explicit solution but I don't know how it can be used since I cannot evaluate it anywhere.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე
1) Mathematica is known for producing illegible answers because dealing with all the poles/branch cuts/other special conditions can be very challenging.  Even simpler things like sqrt and log can be surprisingly complicated.  Sometimes you can simplify things by adding Assumptions->x>0 or w/e.
2) As I said, you haven't supplied enough boundary conditions, so there is no equation to evaluate.  There's probably a c_1(...) floating around somewhere.

Comment: I want that solution with series `x+xy/(1-x)+O(y^2)` that I had there towards the end of the question, but I don't know how to specify it with boundary conditions